# Is it possible to combine the results of multiple SEPARATED select statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL in general,
I don't know if this is already answered or just common knowledge, but I've failed to find similar question.

Is it possible to append multiple select statements when there's other processes between it?
For example,

```
set @a = 1;
#first select
select @a as alphabet;

#random code
set @a = 2;
insert into `dummy`(`iddummy`) values @a;

#second select
select @a as alphabet;
```

and get results like

```
alphabet
--------
1
2
```

I want appended result like that because I'm working with for my front end program, using select to return error message or insert results (for review). This becomes a problem when one of my stored procedure calls other similar procedure, resulting in multiple select results with just one call

Comment: Can you describe more about what "random code" can be? Is it SQL? Does it modify data? Is all the code shown run as part of a single SQL transaction?

Comment: You may collect your "separate outputs" in (temporary) table (INSERT .. SELECT) then select all collected rows at once.

Comment: @Bohemian "random code" in my case is SQL, yes it modifies tables and variables
why I wrote "random code" is because if the select sentences are connected, we could just use union and problem solved

Comment: @Akina
I've never used temporary tables before, how does it work? when does it get reset?
I assume it won't reset per-transaction commit? can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the results of the first query in a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html), then select from it in your final query:

```sql
set @a = 1;
create temporary table query1
select @a as alphabet;
set @a = 2;
insert into dummy(iddummy) values (@a);
select alphabet from query1
union all
select @a;
```

Produces:

| alphabet |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1jqN7Hpj2VjbLBA3CquR/0) (also showing `dummy` was inserted into).